# executing smart query in DD4T does not return any promotions

Tags: dxa, dd4t, smarttarget, dxa-1.7

I can see the promotions are getting filtered out based on triggers properly in QueryServer and Indexer Server Preview mode, but when I am trying fetch the Promotion using SmartTarget API, I am getting no promotions in resultset.

I have created Custom dummy Cartridge for location claim. I am using Keyword based trigger for location in SmartTarget and also configured in `TriggerType.xml` in Fredhopper. For testing I have hard coded the TCM URI of location Keyword I have selected in SmartTarget Promotion.

Below is code snippet I am using for SmartTarget API

```
Util.TcmUri pageUri = new Util.TcmUri(String.Format("tcm:{0}-{1}-64", localization.LocalizationId, smartTargetPageModel.Id));
Util.TcmUri publicationUri = new Util.TcmUri(0, pageUri.PublicationId, 1);

ClaimStore claimStore = AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore;
var locationClaim = claimStore.Get<string>(new Uri("taf:claim:ambientdata:locationcartridge:userlocation"));
string locationId = "tcm:28-695-1024";

if (locationClaim == null)
{
    claimStore.Put(new Uri("taf:claim:ambientdata:locationcartridge:userlocation"), locationId, global::Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Runtime.ClaimType.Normal, global::Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Runtime.ClaimValueScope.Session);
}

string triggers = AmbientDataHelper.GetTriggers(claimStore);

QueryBuilder queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder();
queryBuilder.AddCriteria(new PublicationCriteria(publicationUri));
queryBuilder.AddCriteria(new PageCriteria(pageUri));                
queryBuilder.AddCriteria(new RegionCriteria("Offers"));
queryBuilder.Parse(triggers);

return queryBuilder.Execute();
```

Please note that I have added Query Service capability in Content Discovery service and I am not using TCDL tags in presentation site. In log file of query service, I am not getting error but it does not show that query server is getting called, only getting below log in smart-target log file of query service.

> 2017-05-23 06:24:41,804 INFO  WebServiceExecutor - Trigger-Types are successfully retrieved. Response status code: 200
>
> 2017-05-23 06:24:42,039 INFO  WebServiceExecutor - trigger-types are successfully retrieved
>
> 2017-05-23 06:44:14,020 INFO  ConfigurationUtility - Loading Mappings for Publications
>
> 2017-05-23 06:44:16,763 DEBUG QueryEntityRegister - Registering entity data models
>
> 2017-05-23 07:03:40,954 DEBUG TriggerTypeDataSourceProvider - SelectOperation: Getting all trigger types.
>
> 2017-05-23 07:03:40,995 INFO  WebServiceExecutor - Trigger-Types are successfully retrieved. Response status code: 200
>
> 2017-05-23 07:03:41,200 INFO  WebServiceExecutor - trigger-types are successfully retrieved
>
> 2017-05-23 07:07:48,533 DEBUG TriggerTypeDataSourceProvider - SelectOperation: Getting all trigger types.
>
> 2017-05-23 07:07:48,541 INFO  WebServiceExecutor - Trigger-Types are successfully retrieved. Response status code: 200
>
> 2017-05-23 07:07:48,545 INFO  WebServiceExecutor - trigger-types are successfully retrieved
>
> 2017-05-23 07:07:57,177 DEBUG TriggerTypeDataSourceProvider - SelectOperation: Getting all trigger types.
>
> 2017-05-23 07:07:57,186 INFO  WebServiceExecutor - Trigger-Types are successfully retrieved. Response status code: 200
>
> 2017-05-23 07:07:57,191 INFO  WebServiceExecutor - trigger-types are successfully retrieved

Comment: Please edit your question and include the query you are doing -- either through the source code or a debug log entry.

Comment: That code seems alright. If you do a `queryBuilder.ToString()` does it still include the Publication, Page, and Region criteria? Also, the fact that it doesn't seem to call the query server is very suspicious -- are you sure it's not going to another instance than the one you expected?

Comment: Query service capability is configured on port 8094 in Content deployer server. And this 8094 port is not accessible outside. Does it needs to be opened for the location from where I am executing this code.

Comment: Yes it does.  BTW: I'm confused by the DXA-1.7 tag. Is your Web Application DXA-based? If so, have you considered using the DXA Experience Optimization Module?

Comment: Yes it is web application dxa based and using dd4t.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, I am able to the promotion once port 8094 for query service get opened for presentation server